# Java Instant Messenger - Contact List

Tags: java

I'm building my first Instant Messaging App. Using various tutorials (The New Boston; Head First Java) I have successfully implemented a working client-server that can send receive/messages between one-another.

I now wish to add some slightly advanced features,such as a contact list which allows me to add friends, see when my friends are is online/offline. I'm trying to avoid 3rd party APIs (e.g. Smack), as I wish to learn the basics. Unfortunately, the online tutorials I've read don't go beyond setting up a basic two-party client-server model.

My question is this: How would I implement a basic contact list which links to my below Server.java and Client.java?

Many thanks for any help.

Server.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.Date;//timestamp functionality


public class Server extends JFrame{ //inherits from JFrame

    //1. Instance Variables

    private JTextField userText; //where messages are typed
    private JTextArea chatWindow; //where messages are displayed
    private String fullTimeStamp = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
    //fullTimeStamp - MM = months; mm = minutes; HH = 24-hour clock

    //setting up the streams
    private ObjectOutputStream output; //messages being sent by user
    private ObjectInputStream input; //messages being received by user;

    private ServerSocket server;

    private Socket connection; //Socket = sets up connection between one computer and another.

    //2. Constructor (GUI)
    public Server(){
    super("Mick's Instant Messenger [SERVER]"); //window title
    userText = new JTextField();
    userText.setEditable(false); //you cannot type anything, unless you are connected to someone else
    userText.addActionListener( 
        new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            sendMessage(event.getActionCommand());
            userText.setText(""); //Resets editable text field after you send message
        }
        }
    );
    add(userText, BorderLayout.SOUTH);//places user text input (JTextArea) field at bottom
    chatWindow = new JTextArea(15,30); //displays conversation
    add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow));
    chatWindow.setLineWrap(true); //wraps lines when they outgrow the panel width
    chatWindow.setWrapStyleWord(true); //ensures that above line wrap occurs at word end
    setSize(400,320);
    setVisible(true); //set visible on screen
    }

    //3.Setup and Run the Server
    public void StartRunning(){
        try{
            server = new ServerSocket(6789, 100);
            //Client connects at Port # 6789
            //100 = QueueLength - the backlog of clients who can wait at port #6789 to connect to the Server

            //while(true) ... means this while loop is going to run forever
            while(true){
                try{
                    waitForConnection();
                    setupStreams();
                    whileChatting(); //allows messages to pass back and forth through streams
                }catch(EOFException eofException){

                    //connect and have conversation
                    //Display timestamp for disconnection
                    showMessage("\n\n" + fullTimeStamp);
                    showMessage("\nConnection terminated by SERVER! "); //displays end of stream/connection


                }finally{
                    closeCrap();
                }
            }
        }catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace(); //Displays info where there's an error!
    }
    }

        //4. wait for connection method, then display connection info
        private void waitForConnection() throws IOException{
            showMessage("\n SERVER : Waiting for user(s) to connect... \n "); //tells user Server is waiting for a connection
            connection = server.accept();
            //socket "connection" will accept connections. Creates a socket for each new connection.
            showMessage("Connected with " +connection.getInetAddress().getHostName()); //displays IP address and hostname

        }

        //5. setup streams method.. get streams to send and receive data
        private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            //creates pathway to allow connection to whichever computer the 'connnection' socket created.
            output.flush(); //clears data that gets left over in buffer when you try to connect to someone else. Flushes it over to the other person.
            input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            //no flush here, because you cannot flush someone else's stream
            showMessage("\n Streams are now setup! \n");

        }

        //6. during conversation method

        private void whileChatting() throws IOException{

            //Display timestamp for connection
            showMessage("\n" + fullTimeStamp);

            String message = "You are now connected! \n ";
            sendMessage(message);
            ableToType(true); //will allow user to type into text box after a connection
            String timeStamp = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());//timestamp

            do{
                try{
                    message = (String) input.readObject(); //read incoming message as a String and store in 'message' variable.
                    showMessage("\n" + message);//displays each message you receive on a new line
                }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException){
                    showMessage("/n I don't know what object the user has sent!");
                }

            //***broken by timestamp?***    
            }while(!message.equalsIgnoreCase("CLIENT " + "[" + timeStamp  + "]" + ": " + "END")); //allows conversation until Client enters "END"

        }

        //7. Close Crap method - close streams and sockets after you are finished chatting
        private void closeCrap(){
            showMessage("\n\n Closing connections... \n");
            ableToType(false);
            try{
                output.close(); //close your stream to other users
                input.close(); //close incoming streams
                connection.close(); //close the socket

            }catch(IOException ioException){
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            }
}
        //8. send message method - send message to client
        private void sendMessage(String message){
            try{

                //writeObject method is built into Java.

                String timeStamp = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());//timestamp
                output.writeObject("SERVER" + " [" + timeStamp + "]" + ": " + message);
                showMessage("\nSERVER" + " [" + timeStamp + "]" + ": " + message); //shows the ouput message in our conversation window
                output.flush();
            }catch(IOException ioException){
                chatWindow.append("ERROR: Unable to send message!");
            }
        }

        //9. updates chatWindow - instead of creating entirely new GUI each time
        private void showMessage(final String text){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        chatWindow.setEditable(false); //disallows text editing in chatWindow
                        chatWindow.append(text); //appends text, which was passed in from above
                    }
                }
                );  
}
        //10. Lets user type
        private void ableToType(final boolean tof){
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                    new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            userText.setEditable(tof); //passes in 'true'
                        }
                    }
                    );  

        }
}
```

Client.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Date; //timestamp functionality

import javax.swing.*;

public class Client extends JFrame { //inherits from JFrame

    //1. Creating instance variables

    private JTextField userText; //where user inputs text
    private JTextArea chatWindow; //where messages are displayed
    private String fullTimeStamp = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
    //fullTimeStamp - MM = months; mm = minutes; HH = 24-hour cloc
    private ObjectOutputStream output; //output from Client to Server
    private ObjectInputStream input; //messages received from Server
    private String message ="";
    private String serverIP;
    private Socket connection;

    //2. Constructor (GUI)
    public Client(String host){ //host=IP address of server
        super("Mick's Instant Messenger [CLIENT]");
        serverIP = host; //placed here to allow access to private String ServerIP
        userText = new JTextField();
        userText.setEditable(false);
        userText.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    sendMessage(event.getActionCommand()); //For this to work, must build sendData Method
                    userText.setText(""); //resets userText back to blank, after message has been sent to allow new message(s)
                }
            }

                );
        add(userText, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        chatWindow = new JTextArea();
        add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow), BorderLayout.CENTER); //allows you to scroll up and down when text outgrows chatWindow
        chatWindow.setLineWrap(true); //wraps lines when they outgrow the panel width
        chatWindow.setWrapStyleWord(true); //ensures that above line wrap occurs at word end
        setSize(400,320);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    //3. startRunning method
    public void startRunning(){
        try{
            connectToServer(); //unlike Server, no need to wait for connections. This connects to one specific Server.
            setupStreams();
            whileChatting();
        }catch(EOFException eofException){


            //Display timestamp for disconnection
            showMessage("\n\n" + fullTimeStamp);
            showMessage("\nConnection terminated by CLIENT! ");


        }catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
                closeCrap();
            }

    }

    //4. Connect to Server
    private void connectToServer() throws IOException{
        showMessage(" \n Attempting connection to SERVER... \n");
        connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 6789);//Server IP can be added later
        showMessage(" Connected to: " +connection.getInetAddress().getHostName() ); //displays IP Address of Server
    }

    //5. Setup streams to send and receive messages
    private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        output.flush();
        input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        showMessage("\n Streams are now setup! \n");

    }

    //6. While chatting method
    private void whileChatting() throws IOException{


        //Display timestamp for connection
        showMessage("\n" + fullTimeStamp);

        ableToType(true);
        String timeStamp = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());//timestamp
        do{
            try{
                message = (String) input.readObject(); //read input, treat as String, store in message variable
                showMessage("\n" + message);
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotfoundException){
                showMessage("\n I don't know that object type");
            }

        //***broken by timestamp?***    
        }while(!message.equalsIgnoreCase("SERVER " + "[" + timeStamp  + "]" + ": " + "END")); //Conversation happens until Server inputs 'End'

    }

    //7. Close the streams and sockets
    private void closeCrap(){
        showMessage("\n\nClosing streams and sockets...");
        ableToType(false);//disable typing feature when closing streams and sockets
        try{
            output.close();
            input.close();
            connection.close();
        }catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace(); //show error messages or exceptions
        }
    }

    //8. Send Messages to Server
    private void sendMessage(String message){
        try{
        String timeStamp = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());//timestamp
        output.writeObject("CLIENT" + " [" + timeStamp + "]" + ": " + message);
        output.flush();
        showMessage("\nCLIENT" + " [" + timeStamp + "]" + ": " + message);
    }catch(IOException ioexception){
        chatWindow.append("\n Error: Message not sent!");
    }

    }

    //9.change/update chatWindow
    private void showMessage(final String m){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        chatWindow.setEditable(false); //disallows text editing in chatWindow
                        chatWindow.append(m); //appends text, which was passed in from above
                    }
                }

                );
    }

    //10. Lets user type
            private void ableToType(final boolean tof){
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                        new Runnable(){
                            public void run(){
                                userText.setEditable(tof); //passes in 'true'
}
        }

                        );
            }
}
```

Comment: This sentence "I'm trying to avoid APIs" makes no sense. _Everything_ is an API. What exactly are you trying to say?

Comment: @BoristheSpider: I meant that I'm trying to avoid relying on 3rd party APIs. I am relatively new to this language, so apologies if I've annoyed you by not knowing everything that you do. I have edited my original post to reflect your previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that you want a persistent contact list and not one for one session only. Therefore one solution would be to create accounts based on username and associate an id:

Example your friend logs onto the IM with the name Fred, if this is a new name give it an id and save it somewhere (e.g. text file or simple database)

If you then add Fred as a contact you will need a separate text file or database table to hold contact details for each user. All you will be doing is linking Fred's id to your own.

Then, when you next go into the IM the server should bring up your list of contacts from wherever it is saved

Answer (score 1):

Either create the files and store the recent online users by mapping them to the one whom they are chatting to. Suppose Fred is chatting with `X` and `Y`, so from next time when Fred logs in, he will see `X` and `Y` already being added into his contact list and he should have the option to remove or block them in future. And the same should happen with `X` and `Y`.